# How can I add TextView to Toolbar when I'm using the <include> tag?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

So, I have a toolbar.xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

And, I have an `<include...` tag in my layout:

```
<include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

So I heard if I want to center the title of the activity on the `toolbar`, I simply need to add a `TextVIew` to the toolbar, like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbarLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <TextView .../>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But, I'm using the `include` tag, and the text is apparently not showing up:

```
<include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/createNewOccasion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        </include>
```

So, what can I do to solve the problem? Here's how it's showing up:
[image: How it's showing up]

If you want to see my full real layout, go [here](http://pastebin.com/UGupLRpK).
Here's my activity if it is helpful in anyway: http://pastebin.com/g6ZXAxe5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add a view to your `Toolbar` then you have to add it inside `Toolbar` as a child, and not a child of the include.

You already have this piece of code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbarLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"             
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you only want to show this `TextView` on one `Activity` then set `TextView` `visibility` to `GONE` by default and change it to `VISIBLE` inside your `Activity` where you want to show it.

You can get the `TextView` in any `Activity` where the above layout is included in the main layout.

```
TextView toolbarTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTextView);
```

Comment: But my titles will vary, how will I access the textview in my activity if the toolbar is in a seperate `toolbar.xml`?

Comment: Do I have to do any inflation? Or do I simply say `TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` even though the toolbar is in `toolbar.xml`?

Comment: You can simply get it using findViewById. But if you `R.id.toolbar` if your TextView id is toolbar in the layout.

Comment: That's the problem. I'm using `<include>` in my actual layout, not `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` .

Comment: I don't think my activity could access `toolbar.xml` without any inflation or things like that, can it/

Comment: Please post your complete activity layout and toolbar layout file and Activity code how you are trying to access Toolbar & Textview

Comment: I have mentioned my toolbar layout above, it's the first code block in the question. I'll upload my activity.

Comment: There's no view with id `toolbar` - if you look at your included `Toolbar` its ID is `android:id="@+id/toolbarLL"` - you have to get Toolbar using the id you set in your layout file.

Comment: yes, that was a typo, but it doesn't matter since I'm getting the toolbar via its layout by `<include android:layout="@layout/toolbar.xml.../>`. `toolbar.xml` has the toolbar, and my actual layout uses `include` to use it.

Comment: I'll fix my typo, but it doesn't really matter; I'm not calling on the toolbar anywhere, I'm only calling on the include tab, which automatically calls on the toolbar in the toolbar.xml . When I put `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` I'm referring to the `<include>` tag in my actual layout, not the actual toolbar in its toolbar.xml .

Comment: You are confusing `include` with a view. Include itself is nothing. When your code is complied that include tag is replaced with the toolbar.xml layout. So you have access to toolbar directly just as any other main layout view.

Comment: Aah. Now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: If it fixed you problem then you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Wait a sec, I still can't access the TextView inside the toolbar. I get a NullPointerException when I try accessing it :|

Comment: You know what? I'm also getting another error. I give up, I'm no longer going to use the <include> tag. Thanks anyway. This could help future visitors, so I'll mark it.

Comment: It's really straight forward. If you post your complete clean code in the question then I can take a look at it.